# JSON update not working

Tags: json, scala, solr

I tried to insert this into sole using the `update/json` handler:

```
[{"id":"abc","text":"you have been served"}]
```

But Solr gives me this hard-to-troubleshoot message. I am using Scala + Dispatch HTTP, whic is new for me. I am kinda experienced with Solr, but this error message is unhelpful. What exactly is this message?

I am using the latest version 3.6, using the start.jar (for testing) and have disabled lazy loading for `update/json`.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /update/json. Reason:
<pre>    NOT_FOUND</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
localhost:8983/solr/update...
```

I was careless enough to

```
localhost:8983/update...
```

My bad.